# TreeView prevHoveredNode

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, treeview, sender

How do I use prevHoveredNode property handling event of TreeView?

Event is fired when I click on a node of a TreeView (TSTViewAnalisi)

In output window I read the correct value but when I compile a project, VS2019 marks one error of non existing property.

```vb
Private Sub TSTViewAnalisi_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TSTViewAnalisi.MouseUp 
    Dim a As String = sender.SelectedNode.prevHoveredNode.Text
```

Comment: What `prevHoveredNode` ? No such property if you are talking about `System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`,

Answer (score 0):

The basic [EventHandler Delegate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.eventhandler?view=net-6.0) passes you an `Object` as the first parameter. `Object` does not have a definition of `SelectedNode`. But this is expected and common, and you just need to cast the sender to the appropriate type,

```vb
Dim s = DirectCast(sender, TreeView)
Dim a = s.SelectedNode.prevHoveredNode.Text
```

or you could directly access the control

```vb
Dim a = TSTViewAnalisi.SelectedNode.prevHoveredNode.Text
```